# Button not running javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So this should be changing the page so that when they click the button it shows a total of everything they have selected in the form, but it is not doing anything. It seems that it is not even running the script at all, and I have no idea what is up.

```
...more form stuff up here    
<button type="button" onclick="total(this.form)">Get my Total</button>

    <p id="subtotal"></p>

    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
    function total(form)
    {
    var SynCr= form.Synth.value;
    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML="You have ordered: <br>"+SynCr+" Synth");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get in the console? Also, what's `form.Synth.value`?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `onclick="total(this.form)"`. When the handler is called `this` refers to the button, which does not have a form as a member.

Try instead:

```
onclick="total(document.getElementById('formId'))"
```

Comment: If the button is a direct child of the form, you can also do `onclick="total(this.parentNode)"

Comment: You should see some kind of error in your console (use Chrome and open developer tools, for instance). Perhaps form.Synth is a syntax error. Since you didn't include the whole form, it's impossible for us to tell what the problem is.

Comment: And you have to replace 'formId' with the true ID of your form or that will be null as well. If your form doesn't have an ID set it to id="formId" to get the above code working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
`this.form` does not return the parent form.
Second: you have a syntax error in: `document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML="You have ordered: <br>"+SynCr+" Synth");` the last `)` should not be there.

The following is sinppet of code shows you in some what how to debug your code and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="hgg">
  <input type="text" name="Synth" value="" />
  <button type="button" onclick="total(this)">Get my Total</button>
  </form>
  <div id="subtotal">
    <p>5518</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function total(button)
    {
      form1 = button.parentNode;
      alert(form1.Synth.value)
      /*alert(p.id)
      alert("555");*/
     SynCr= form1.Synth.value;
      alert(SynCr)
   k = document.getElementById("subtotal");
      k.innerHTML = "You have ordered: <br>"+SynCr+"Synth";
    }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Look at this online demo: http://jsbin.com/voruzumi/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, everything got worked out. Separating each step into its own line definitely helps with debugging

Comment: @user3338822 Very nice to hear that. Don't forget to set the best answer.